# How to install AIDL in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, buildozer

I tried convert python app to apk in GitHub Actions, but in step "Build in Buildozer" GitHub raised: "Aidl not found, please install it.". How can I do it?

buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

title = MyApp

package.name = myapp

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf

version = 1.0

requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd

presplash.filename = presplash.png

icon.filename = icon.png

orientation = portrait

osx.python_version = 3

osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

fullscreen = 1

android.presplash_color = #009696

android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

build.yml:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 1,15 * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get Date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
        shell: bash

      - name: Cache Buildozer global directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer_global
          key: buildozer-global-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.get-date.outputs.date }}-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - name: Build with Buildozer
        uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
        id: buildozer
        with:
          command: buildozer -v android debug
          buildozer_version: master

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
sudo apt-get install aidl
```

from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930460/aidl-not-found-please-install-it) in build.yml in run of first step
(

```
- name: Get Date
  id: get-date
  run: |
      echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install build-essential
      sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
      sudo apt-get install aidl 
  shell: bash
```

).
But it's not works, and as I understand, it is option only for pc

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason from [this question](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1357), which would solve enough to change buildozer -v android debug to echo y | buildozer -v android debug.
New file yml:

name: CI

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 1,15 * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get Date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
        shell: bash

      - name: Cache Buildozer global directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer_global
          key: buildozer-global-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.get-date.outputs.date }}-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - name: Build with Buildozer
        uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
        id: buildozer
        with:
          command: echo y | buildozer -v android debug
          buildozer_version: master

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```